# How to retreive time from tizen timepicker (or is there a better way to do it with jQuery?)

Tags: jquery-ui, timepicker, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am working on a tizen web application for a Gear S3 watch and need to implement a time picker to set an alarm. I copied some code from the internet but it creates the entire time picker in js using the inbuilt TAU and I can't seem to access it.

This is the HTML:

```
   <div class="ui-content">
    <div class="ui-time-picker"></div>
   </div>
```

This is the JS

```
(function () {
var page = document.getElementById("number-picker-page"),
element = page.querySelector(".ui-time-picker"),
widget = null;

function init() 
{
    widget = tau.widget.TimePicker(element);
}


page.addEventListener("pagebeforeshow", init);

}());
```

Screenshot of the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/liMjs.jpg

Edit:
Here is the link which I referred to for the code:
https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/latest/ui_fw_api/Wearable_UIComponents/wearable_timepicker.htm

Answer (score 0):

The latest TAU release  has fix for this issue.
https://github.com/Samsung/TAU/releases/tag/v1.0.16

```
widget = tau.widget.TimePicker(element);
widget.value(); // returns Date object
```